# Suggestions for improving mixed models question

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[When are zero-correlation mixed models theoretically sound?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205975/when-are-zero-correlation-mixed-models-theoretically-sound)

I think the above question is well formulated and worthwhile.  However, it didn't get any attention, so I put a bounty on it.  The bounty will now expire in two days.  Although it has now gotten 18 upvotes, it hasn't gotten any answers and has attracted only one comment.

- Can anyone think of anything that will help bring more attention to this question?
- Is there anything that could be added / clarified that might make it more likely to attract an answer?

Comment: Bounties can help, but unfortunately the "hit rate" for bounties isn't especially high; on a good question it seems like it's somewhere in the vicinity of 50-50. On the plus side, the most likely time for an answer is when it bubbles to near the top of the bounty list .. i.e. in the last day or so..., so you may well still get an answer on it (indeed many of the best answers have appeared in the last day or so); one I awarded actually came just *after* the end of the bounty period (but before the end of the 24 hour grace period to award the bounty - ...

Comment: ... in effect a bounty lasts an extra day where it's not in the list but someone who saw it might still answer and can still be awarded the bounty). I wish I felt competent to give it an answer, but I don't think I have enough of a handle on that.

Comment: By now it's the second most upvoted unanswered question by the way. (Why does *the* most upvoted unanswered question have so many upvotes I don't understand.)

Comment: @amoeba, I see it as the 3rd (although #2 is a closed question). I also note that even this meta-Q doesn't seem to be getting much attention.

Comment: I see it as the second on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered. I don't think closed questions are shown on this page at all, so I am wondering which page you were looking at.

Comment: Honestly, I am not very surprised that clarpaul's question does not get a good answer; I am rather surprised that it gathered 21 upvotes.

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0) is the search (sorted by votes). I guess the unanswered tab doesn't list closed Qs, which makes sense. Why are you surprised / not, @amoeba?

Comment: I am not following mixed-model questions but my impression was that this is one of the topics that are not very well represented on CV; we don't have many active people here with detailed knowledge of the mixed model theory. (Perhaps there is nobody at all.) So I am not surprised that a difficult, long, and technical question remains unanswered. Have you tried to ping @BenBolker somehow? He is (by far) the top answerer in the [mixed-model] tag and I remember coming across very good answers of his.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how appropriate that would be, @amoeba. I'm sure he's aware of it, & he is one of the authors on the paper the Q is asking about. The silence is deafening.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize he was one of the authors! Perhaps he doesn't have time for it now, but I don't see why it would not be appropriate to ping him.